# How to Alight table texts in email template

Tags: html, html-email

How do I update email template to align the all table sections texts left, see image link. The table columns title and contents are not aligned, the title top is centered and bottom is left. I am not sure where to correct the issue. Any assistance will be very welcomed. Please let me know if you have any questions, or would like the image resent.

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Learning Assignment Update</title>

  <style>
    /**This is to overwrite Outlook.com’s Embedded CSS************/
    
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0 auto !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: separate;
    }
    
    a,
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #2BA6CB
    }
    
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    h2,
    h2 a,
    h2 a:visited,
    h3,
    h3 a,
    h3 a:visited,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    .t_cht {
      color: #9B301C !important
    }
    
    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td {
      line-height: 100%
    }
    /**This is to center your email in Outlook.com************/
    
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* ------------------------------------- 
TYPOGRAPHY 
------------------------------------- */
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    p.lead {
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    h1 small,
    h2 small,
    h3 small,
    h4 small,
    h5 small,
    h6 small {
      font-size: 60%;
      color: #6f6f6f;
      line-height: 0;
      text-transform: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 44px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 37px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 27px;
    }
    
    h4 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 23px;
    }
    
    h5 {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    h6 {
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #444;
    }
    
    p.lead {
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    /* My Table Styles */
    
    .myTable {
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      /*margin: 20px;*/
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .myTH {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #009999;
      color: #009999;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      padding: 10px 8px;
    }
    
    .myTD {
      color: #585858;
      padding: 9px 8px 0;
    }
    /* Odds and ends */
    
    .column {
      width: 300px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .column tr td {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .column-wrap {
      padding: 0!important;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 600px!important;
    }
    
    .column table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .social .column {
      width: 280px;
      min-width: 279px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    table.social {
      /* padding:15px; */
      background-color: #ebebeb;
    }
    
    .social .soc-btn {
      padding: 3px 7px;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    a.fb {
      background-color: #3B5998!important;
    }
    
    a.tw {
      background-color: #1daced!important;
    }
    
    a.gp {
      background-color: #DB4A39!important;
    }
    
    a.ms {
      background-color: #000!important;
    }
    
    .sidebar .soc-btn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body width="100%">
  <center style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
        <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%;">


          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="align=" center " style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px; " height="20 ">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
          <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px; " width="560 ">


<table cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " border="0 " style="padding:5px;margin:0px;width:100%;background-color:#ebebeb; ">
<tr>
<td><img style="margin: 10px; height: 50px; width: 200px; " alt="Logo " src="https://wcb.benefitpad.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2018/05/New-WCB-Logo.png " /></td>
<td align="right "><h6>Learning Assignment Update</h6></td></tr>
</table>


<table cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " border="0 " width="100% ">
<tr>
<td style="height: 40px ">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Hi <FIRST_NAME/>,</h3>
<LOOP>
<p class="lead "><label key="notification.ApmStudentLearningPlanNotification.MessageText1 "/><CPNTS_ADDED_ROLLUP/></p>
<p><table cellspacing="0 " class="myTable ">
<tr>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Type</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course ID</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course Title</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Due Date</th>
</tr>

<LOOP>
<tr>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TYPE_ID_ADDED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_ID_ADDED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TITLE_ADDED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_DUE_DATE_ADDED/></td>
</tr></LOOP></table></LOOP>
</p>

<LOOP>
<p class="lead "><label key="notification.ApmStudentLearningPlanNotification.MessageText2 "/><CPNTS_MODIFIED_ROLLUP/></p>
<p><table cellspacing="0 " class="myTable ">
<tr>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Type</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course ID</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course Title</th>
</tr>

<LOOP>
<tr>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TYPE_ID_MODIFIED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_ID_MODIFIED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TITLE_MODIFIED/></td>
</tr></LOOP></table></LOOP>
</p>

<LOOP>
<p class="lead "><label key="notification.ApmStudentLearningPlanNotification.MessageText3 "/><CPNTS_DELETED_ROLLUP/></p>
<p><table cellspacing="0 " class="myTable ">
<tr>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Type</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course ID</th>
<th scope="col " class="myTH ">Course Title</th>
</tr>

<LOOP>
<tr>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TYPE_ID_DELETED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_ID_DELETED/></td>
<td class="myTD "><CPNT_TITLE_DELETED/></td>
</tr></LOOP></table></LOOP>
</p>
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td style="height: 40px ">&nbsp;</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " border="0 " style="padding:20px;margin:0px;width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF; ">
<tr>
</tr>
</table> 
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td> 
<!-- column 1 -->
<table cellpadding="0 " cellspacing="0 " border="0 " style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%;background-color:#ebebeb; ">
<tr><td valign="top ">
<table align="left " class="column " style="width:300px ">
<tr>
<td>
<p>Click below to get started or to visit Team Member Central:</p>
<p><strong><a href="https://plateau.com/ ">Get Started!</a></strong></p></td></tr>
</table><!-- /column 1 --></td>

</td>
<td style="padding:0px;margin:0px; ">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3 " style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px; " height="20 ">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<p>Contact your Human Resources for Questions. This email address in unattended. Please Do Not Reply.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start over and follow proper table structure. Your tables are a mess and until you clean that up, it's really hard to help.

As an example, this is not valid table structure:

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
    <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%;">
```

The reason it's not valid is you started a table row without a parent `<table>`. You did not close the `<tr>`, the `<td>` or the `<table>`.

This is a valid basic table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table cell a</td>
        <td>table cell b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Either start from scratch and rebuild or use an html code validator like this one:

http://jonaquino.blogspot.com/2013/05/unclosed-tag-finder.html

I recommend starting over. I just find it's easier.

By default, a `<td>` will text align left, a `<th>` will text align center. You're not seeing that behavior because the structure is a mess.

Also, `<LOOP>` is not a valid html tag. Even if it was, you're not closing it anywhere `<LOOP></LOOP>`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions to fix table as it is, it will not be easier for me to start all over. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to update the row with from <th> to <td> as i noticed that row was centered and that fixed it. I appreciate your help

Comment: Since you're new to Stack Overflow, choose an answer that worked and close out the open question. Good luck with emails.